# How to avoid duplicate records in one-to-many association without using distinct?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have two tables `issues` and `time_entries` and they have `one-to-many` association between them. We can created multiple `time_entries` for an `issue`.

here is some example data,

**issue**

```
id  |  subject  |  description
------------------------------
1   |  test     |  test
2   |  test1    |  test1
3   |  test2    |  test2
```

**Time entries**

```
id  | issue_id  |  hours | spent_on   | created_on
---------------------------------------------------
1   |  1        |  2     | 2016-12-23 | 2016-12-23
2   |  1        |  2     | 2016-12-23 | 2016-12-23
3   |  2        |  3     | 2016-12-23 | 2016-12-23
4   |  2        |  5     | 2016-12-23 | 2016-12-23
5   |  4        |  4     | 2016-12-23 | 2016-12-23
```

Now I want to fetch all the `issues` which have spent time after a particular date.

```
SELECT *
FROM "issues"
INNER JOIN "time_entries" ON "time_entries"."issue_id" = "issues"."id"
WHERE time_entries.created_on > '2016-12-22'
```

It's returning multiple records for `issues` which have more than one entries.

```
id   | subject  | description
-----------------------------
1   |  test     |  test
1   |  test     |  test
2   |  test1    |  test1
2   |  test1    |  test1
3   |  test2    |  test2
```

How can I avoid these duplicate records without using `distinct`. I can't use `distinct` due to technical reasons in my application.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which database are you using, MySQL or Postgres?  They are fairly different from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id,
                t1.subject,
                t1.description
FROM issues t1
INNER JOIN time_entries t2
    ON t2.issue_id = t1.id
WHERE t2.created_on > '2016-12-22'
```

If you can't use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`, then one other option would be to use a subquery which aggregates over issues in the `time_entries` table and determines which issues meet the requirement.  Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.subject,
       t1.description
FROM issues t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT issue_id
    FROM time_entries
    GROUP BY issue_id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN created_on > '2016-12-22' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
) t2
    ON t2.issue_id = t1.id
```

Comment: I can't use `distinct` or `group by` due to some technical issues in my application.

Comment: @RamizRaja I gave you an option which does not require either of these.

Comment: Just curious, does postgres have `exists`?

Comment: @Alex Yes, Postgres has an `EXISTS` clause, q.v. [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/exists.php).  This might be yet another way of doing this without `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM "issues" 
INNER JOIN "time_entries" ON "time_entries"."issue_id" = "issues"."id"
WHERE time_entries.created_on > '2016-12-22' 
group by id
```

Comment: This would only work on certain versions of MySQL, and even then it is not ideal because you don't for certain _which_ records would be chosen for each `id` value.